# Setting up Nancy windows authorization

Tags: c#, authorization, nancy

Im building a webpage using Nancy, I need to know the identity of the user.
So far i have been inspired by http://www.horsdal-consult.dk/2013/10/supporting-single-sign-on-in-your-nancy.html

However Context.CurrentUser.UserName is always "", I was expecting a username. (I have a breakpoint on the "return View" line)

```
public MyModule(){

  Get["/"] = _ =>
                {
                    return View["Welcome"];
                };

            }
```

Comment: Which parts of the code in the post have you copied? Does the current thread have a claims principal on it? How is your app hosted?

Comment: I copied both code blocks from your homepage. The app is running inside Nancy started from vs2013. On Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Claims  have a role and a name

Comment: Could you set breakpoints in the application startup and begin request handlers to see if they are hit?

Comment: This is my very first Nancy project, so that might be why I don't quiet get it(it might be something very simple). I have set a breakpoint inside SetUser.Initialize and it is hit. Should I specify somewhere I want authorization?

Comment: How about a breakpoint inside the lamba added to the BeforeRequest pipeline in SetUser.Initialize. Is that hit when requests are received? That is at line 7 in the second code snippet in my post.

Comment: Intialize is hit. however the Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Name is "" and Thread.CurrentPrincipal.IsAutenticated is false